# Unable to add a background image in CSS or HTML

Tags: html, css

I have linked my HTML to CSS between the  tags

`<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

In my CSS style sheet the code reads

```
body {
    background:url("file://C:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/HTML/Wesbite/backgroundimage";
}
```

MY HTML file, Style Sheet and background image are all in the same folder. Can someone please troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {background: url("yourimage.png"); }

Do not forget set a extension for image such as png, gif, jpg....
```

Answer (score 1):

`body {background:url('backgroundimage.jpg'); }`

You forgot a closing bracket and should really use relative paths.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however the image will still not appear. How should i go about using a relative path to acheive this?

Comment: simply enter your filename including extension, without a path (if they're all in the same dir)

Answer (score 1):

You forget about filename extension.

```
body {
    background: url('backgroundimage.jpg');
}
```

You have to find out the filename extension - enable filename extensions in windows explorer or use file manager like total commander to show it.